# Make private repositories in organization visible to a group of people

Tags: github

I have a GitHub organization account containing mostly private repositories.

When a new private repository is added, I would like an entire group of people to all be given write access to the repository, but I don't see a way to achieve this.

Ideally I would like to give everyone access that has a `*@domain.com` address tied to their github account, but I don't know if that is possible.

I would settle for creating a team with everyone and automatically adding that team any time a new repository is created.

I don't see any way to achieve this, but maybe I am missing something simple.

Comment: According to the GitHub documentation, you can create a team on the organization, where you can add members and give them access. Then you can add repositories to the team (https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-team-access-to-an-organization-repository). Are you looking for something like that?

Comment: @Sara this may be the best option, but not quite what I am looking for. I would like a "default" permission to be assigned to every new repository, rather than have to manually add a team to each new repository.

Comment: Lots of people have the ability to create a new organization repo, but no one remembers to add others to their repo. This results in a hodepgdge of people being added to repositories at random by the owner. Ideally I would like everyone in the org to be able to see all the repositories without being explicitly granted access.

Comment: Can't you set the base permissions, as indicated here: https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/setting-base-permissions-for-an-organization#setting-base-permissions
(?)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! If you make an answer I will accept it.